# How can a shell script avoid the SIGPIPE that would be caused by use of closed file descriptor?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

A shell script can lose its standard and other file descriptors if the other end goes away. One way this can happen is by terminating a `ssh` client used to launch the script:

```
$ ssh localhost test
^C
```

This launches a `bash` script called `test` over SSH and a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is used to terminate the `ssh` command. This does not terminate `test` which continues running but it does close the attached file descriptors (e.g. standard input/output/error).

If `test` tries to use those closed file descriptors then it will terminate with a `SIGPIPE`. A simple `echo` will suffice.

One of the things `test` might have is a `log` function that uses `echo` to write messages to the systemd journal and also to standard error. Something like this:

```
log() {
 echo "$*" | systemd-cat -t test
 echo >&2 "$*"
}
```

The second `echo` raises a `SIGPIPE` after the `ssh` session is killed (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). This can be protected against, so that execution continues without the offending `echo`, by putting the `echo` in a subshell:

```
( echo >&2 "$*" )
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: **Writing** stdout or stderr will SIGPIPE (perhaps not immediately); reading stdin will just EOF.

Answer (score 3):

You could if you want ignore SIGPIPE in the script:

```
trap "" PIPE
```

Comment: true, but I wondererd if there was a way to avoid the signal in the first place, by detecting the closed fd and not calling the command (`echo`) that would cause the signal.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only widely-available way to check whether a file descriptor is open in a shell script is to use `-t`: `[[ -t 2 ]] && echo >&2 "$*"`. This checks whether file descriptor 2 is open and attached to a terminal. Unfortunately this requires the SSH session to have a terminal (`ssh -t`), which terminates the process with `SIGHUP` when you press Ctrl+C! You could work around that too but it's probably not worth it. If you don't care about the error messages when the script is run *via* SSH then it might be acceptable though (with the usual time-of-check-to-time-of-us caveat).

Comment: would  `trap "exec 2>/dev/null" PIPE`  works ?