# Using pipes to list the first two and last two users on the system?

Tags: pipe, tail, head, who

I have to use the  `who` command to display who's online, then use pipes to display the first and last 2 users online. the only thing I know how to do is something like:

`who | head -5 | tail -2` .

That doesn't work, though.

Comment: you can combine multiple commands inside `()` or `{}` separated by `;`... see [Command-Grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

Comment: First and last users in terms of what? Just from the output?

Comment: Similar: [Command to display first few and last few lines of a file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/48777)

Answer (score 4):

Directly:

```
who | head -2
who | tail -2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` and a redirection to `stderr`

```
who | tee >(head -n2 1>&2 ) | tail -n2
```

Where `tee` allows you to copy `stdin` to both a file and `stdout`. Here we actually replace the file by the `head` command and redirect its output from `stdout` to `stderr` (via `1>&2`) as all of `stout` is piped to the `tail` command and processed, so we need to circumvent `tail`ing the `head` result, too. `stderr` itself is however still printed on the terminal.

---

**Updates following discussion in comments**

As pointed out by Stéphane, `head` might send a SIGPIPE signal kill the pipe prematurely so that `tail` might not see the actual end of the input stream.

To prevent this, one could ignore the SIGPIPE signal as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322876/123460), by using a `trap` with an empty command. Tested in `bash` only .....

```
who | { trap "" PIPE ; tee >( head -n 2 3>&1 >&2  ) ; } | tail -n 2
```

Additionally mentioned in the comments: non-`bash` shells might tumble the ordering of the results - see the proposed solution by Stéphane for this.

Comment: `who -l | ( tee >(head -n2 1>&3 ) | tail -n2 ) 3>&1` will ensure both `head` and `tail` write to _stdout_.

Comment: Depending on timing and on the number of logged-in users, `tee` may get a SIGPIPE when `head` terminates so that `tee` would not be able to write the full output to `tail`. Also, as `head` and `tail` run in parallel, the order of their output is not guaranteed.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can confirm the SIGPIPE problem simulating with a large enough `seq` as `stdin` - order is never tumbled, but `tail` does not show the last two number of the `seq`uence. However I do not understand properly what is happening. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If `head` finishes before `tee` has written all the data to the pipe to `head`, then the next time `tee` write to that pipe it will get a SIGPIPE and die. `tail` will output the last two lines it has received before that.

Comment: With `bash`, the order will be preserved because `bash` (at least current versions) process substitution leaves a `bash` process around with its stdout still connected to the pipe to `tail` waiting for the `head` command, so `tail` won't see eof until that process has terminated so not until head has terminated. Other shells like `ksh93` or `zsh` don't have that limitation, so you may see the output tumbled there. One way to guarantee the order with any shell would be with `tee >(head -n 2 3>&1 >&2) | tail -n 2`. Here that fd 3 holds the pipe to tail open.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks - updated with a possible way of ignoring the SIGPIPE

Comment: With `trap "" PIPE`, with some `tee` implementations, you'll still get an error message about the broken pipe. You may want to replace `head -n2` with `sed '1,2!d'`. But then you might as well do the whole thing in `sed`. See for instance: [Command to display first few and last few lines of a file](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/66417)

Answer (score -1):

It goes wrong for you when you are trying to use `tail` command. You are not actually using it to extract what you want from `who` command's output but from `head` command.

If you need to use `head` and `tail` combined with piping, you could do it like this for example:

`(who |head -n5 && who |tail -n2)`

Modify numbers to meet your needs

Comment: This won't work because `head` will eat up all of _stdin_, leaving nothing for `tail`.

Comment: @roaima I see where it went wrong now. But there's one weird thing I don't uderstand at all. I tried to run following command `ls -l |(head -n5 && tail -n2)`. I tested it 10 times now,  6 times I got the result I wanted and 4 times I didn't. Why is that?

Comment: @jiipeezz, that very much depends on timing and the number of files in the directory. It depends whether the first `read()` done by `head` reads the whole output of `ls -l` or not.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for elaborating. Now it makes more sense. Corrected the answer to something that works.